# How do you turn coordinates vertical in Map composer?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, print-composer, mapping

When using map composer in QGIS, there is the option to `Draw coordinates'. once selected, the coordinates are situated in the horizontal position (as seen below).

[image]

Does anyone know how to align the coordinates so they are situated in a vertical position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see picture below->Map Grid properties:
[image]